# Make curve in Bottom Tab navigation React native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

[image: Curved Bottom Tab Bar]

> I want to implement this design using React Native. For navigation
> purpose I am using React Navigation 5. I tried using react-native SVG. Not having good knowledge in svg designing.
> Here is the sample code.

```
import Svg, { Path } from 'react-native-svg';
import * as shape from 'd3-shape';
```

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

```
const height = 64;

const tabWidth = width / 4;

const AnimatedSvg = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Svg)

const left = shape.line()
    .x(d => d.x)
    .y(d => d.y)
    ([
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: width, y: 0 }
    ]);

const right = shape.line()
    .x(d => d.x)
    .y(d => d.y)
    ([
        { x: width + tabWidth, y: 0 },
        { x: width * 2, y: 0 },
        { x: width * 2, y: height },
        { x: 0, y: height },
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
    ])

const tab = shape.line()
    .x(d => d.x)
    .y(d => d.y)
    .curve(shape.curveBasis)
    ([
        { x: width, y: 0 },
        { x: width + 5, y: 0 },
        { x: width + 10, y: 0 },
        { x: width + 15, y: height },
        { x: width + tabWidth - 15, y: height },
        { x: width + tabWidth - 10, y: 10 },
        { x: width + tabWidth -5, y: 0 },
    ])

const d = `${right} ${left} ${tab}`;


const Test = () => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ea3345', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
                <View style={{ height }}>
                    <AnimatedSvg
                        style={{
                            transform:[
                                {
                                    translateX:-100
                                }
                            ]
                        }} 
                        width={width*2} 
                        {...{height}}>
                        <Path {...{ d }} fill="white" />
                    </AnimatedSvg>
                    
                </View>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default Test
```

> Please help me to achieve this kind of design. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you able to implement this?

Comment: Yes, We have to use custom tab bar as per the react navigation 6. There we can pass a custom view. Make the custom view absolute. and set the svg as image background