# How to create a circle under the bottom tab below as attached in linked image

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbRCA.jpg)

Currently I can only do this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdNPU.jpg)
Please help me adjust it to match the required interface, I am using the @react-navigation/bottom-tabs library, please give me a reasonable solution, I really need your help.

Comment: Your question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029467/make-curve-in-bottom-tab-navigation-react-native, and they had to implement a custom component for their goal. You will probably also have to do the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize tab bar this way.

```
<Tab.Navigator
 tabBar={({state, descriptors, navigation, insets})=>{
  return (
   <View
   style={{
    ...
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
   }}>
    <Image source={require(your menu background image)}/>
    // implement your tab items with handling press event to navigate to an appropriate tab screen.
   </View
  )
 }}
...
</Tab.Navigator>
```

check this [sample](https://github.com/jonasbeckdev/dlis/blob/bfd77b91be2126b457603ce8312b43dabe829289/src/screens/TabScreen.tsx#L237).